# Kendo Grid , show command buttons only when adding a new record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid to display data. Currently it's working good with command buttons (update/cancel or edit/delete).

**Issue** : I need to show the command buttons (update/cancel) only when i am adding a new record. But need to hide the buttons (edit/delete) when loading and re-loading the grid.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by hiding them in `dataBound` event:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   ...
   dataBound: function(e){ e.sender.tbody.find('.k-grid-edit,.k-grid-delete').hide() }
});
```

MVC:

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid<..>()
    ...
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("function(e){ e.sender.tbody.find('.k-grid-edit,.k-grid-delete').hide()"))
```

Comment: It Works ... gr8  .. Thank you